# Database Not passing Values

Tags: android

In my application I am using database and I applied for cursor to open data base and pass the data to another calss but the problem is my cursor was showing null values. I am not understanding what is the wrong in my code so any one can help me to come out this situation.

```
        Cursor cur3 = db3.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName ,  null);

        /*
         * db3.rawQuery(" SELECT "+pretestTable+"."+columnID+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+DDL_Testing_Session+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+Text_Reason+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+Text_Howmany+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+Text_Ques1+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques2a+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques2b+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques3+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+TXT_Ques4+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques5+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques6+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques7+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques8+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques9+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+DDL_Sick+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+TXT_Ques11+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques12+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+TXT_Ques13+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+TXT_Ques14+","+   
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques15+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques16+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+RBL_Ques17+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+TXT_Ques18+","+
                " "+pretestTable+"."+TXT_Vct+" FROM "+pretestTable+
                " Inner join "+fingerTable+" ON "+ pretestTable+"."+columnID+" = "+fingerTable+"."+Template11+" WHERE "+pretestTable+"."+"PretestID=?" ,  null);

         * 
         * 
         * 
        SELECT tbl_pre_test.ID,
 tbl_pre_test.ddlTestingSession,
 tbl_pre_test.txtReason,
 tbl_pre_test.txthowmany,
 tbl_pre_test.txtques1,
 tbl_pre_test.rblques2a, 
tbl_pre_test.rblques2b,
 tbl_pre_test.rblques3, 
tbl_pre_test.txtques4,
 tbl_pre_test.rblques5,
 tbl_pre_test.rblques6,
 tbl_pre_test.rblques7, tbl_pre_test.rblques8, tbl_pre_test.rblques9, tbl_pre_test.ddlsick, tbl_pre_test.txtques11, tbl_pre_test.rblques12, tbl_pre_test.txtques13, tbl_pre_test.txtques14, tbl_pre_test.rblques15, tbl_pre_test.rblques16, tbl_pre_test.rblques17, tbl_pre_test.txtques18, tbl_pre_test.txtVCT,
 tbl_finger.template
 FROM tbl_pre_test 
Inner join  tbl_finger On tbl_pre_test.ID = tbl_finger.template
Where tbl_pre_test.PretestID = 20 



        */

        try {

            db3  = this.openOrCreateDatabase("remoteid.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(cur3 != null )    
            {   
              if(cur3.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do {
                        valueOfID =  cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("PretestID"));
                         valuOfDate = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                         textType = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtVCT"));                                                      
                         valueOfDDLTS = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("ddlTestingSession"));
                         valueOfReason = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtReason"));
                         valueOfHowmany = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txthowmany"));
                         valueOftxtques1 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtques1"));
                         valueOfrblques2a = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques2a"));
                         valueOfrblques2b = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques2b"));
                         valueOfrblques3 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques3"));
                         valueOftxtques4 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtques4"));
                         valueOfrblques5 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques5"));
                         valueOfrblques6 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques6"));
                         valueOfrblques7 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques7"));
                         valueOfrblques8 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques8"));
                         valueOfrblques9 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques9"));
                         valueOfddlsick = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("ddlsick"));
                         valueOftxtques11 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtques11"));
                         valueOfrblques12 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques12"));
                         valueOftxtques13 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtques13"));
                         valueOftxtques14 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtques14"));
                         valueOfrblques15 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques15"));
                         valueOfrblques16 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques16"));
                         valueOfrblques17 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("rblques17"));
                         valueOftxtques18 = cur3.getString(cur3.getColumnIndex("txtques18"));


                         bundle.getString(valueOfID);
                         bundle.getString(valuOfDate);
                         bundle.getString(textType);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfDDLTS);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfReason);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfHowmany);
                         bundle.getString(valueOftxtques1);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques2a);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques2b);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques3);
                         bundle.getString(valueOftxtques4);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques5);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques6);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques7);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques9);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfddlsick);
                         bundle.getString(valueOftxtques11);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques12);                         
                         bundle.getString(valueOftxtques13);
                         bundle.getString(valueOftxtques14);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques15);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques16);
                         bundle.getString(valueOfrblques17);
                         bundle.getString(valueOftxtques18); 

                    }while (cur3.moveToNext());
                }
            }

        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error", e);

        } finally {
            if (db3 != null)
                db3.close();
        }
        cur3.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Database Cursor Passing Null Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880751/android-database-cursor-passing-null-values)

Answer (score 0):

You call `db.rawQquery()` only after calling `openOrCreateDatabase()`